# IllegalStateException complaining PowerMockRule being loaded by powermock classloader rather than system classloader

Tags: java, junit, powermock, mockstatic

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(StaticMethodsHolder.class)

public class MockNTestStaticMethodsHolder {

  @Rule public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

  @Test public void staticSvcClientMethod () {

    // blah blah blah
    mockstatic (StaticMethodsHolder.class);

    expect (StaticMethodsHolder.TomBradyIsStillTheBest()).andReturn(UNQUESTIONABLY);
    expect (StaticMethodsHolder.NEPatriotsStillTheBest()).andReturn(MAYBE);
    expect (StaticMethodsHolder.NEPatriotsLiiWereIdiots()).andReturn(TOTALLY);
    expect (StaticMethodsHolder.NEPatriotsWinsLiii()).andReturn(RU_KIDDING_ME);

  }

}
```

Maven dependencies/properties in the following order:

1. powermock-version 1.6.6
2. easymock-version 3.4
3. easymock
4. powermock-module-junit4
5. powermock-api-easymock
6. powermock-module-junit4-rule-agent
   (removing this causes constructor issues)
7. powermock-module-junit4-rule
   (removing this dependency has no effect)
8. powermock-classloading-xstream

Runtime error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException PowerMockRule can only be used
with the system classloader but was loaded by
org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.
```

PowerMock is biting is own tail. It wants to use its own classloader, but the JVM says PowerMockRule must be loaded by system's.

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: I am using JDK8.

Comment: you shouldn't have any issue with the question you just deleted (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49056680/how-to-reference-a-function-directly-in-the-functionalinterface-argument-of-a-me). Have you found the solution or was it a simple typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already using the PowermockRunner, you do not need to use the rule.

https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/powermockrule

if you were using a different runner while requiring Powermock functionality that is the use case for the Rule.